# 16 channel security camera system

Tags: camera, security, dvr, nvr

I need a system that can work offline and does not need subscription and that I can see the live feed in Chrome. I also want the cameras to be somewhat vandalproof so they aren't easily damaged by vandals.
Where is it possible to find such systems?
Is there a way to buy such system on amazon? I already have 4 dvr cameras but the dvr is from Annke and is causing a lot of issues. I want to replace it with another system that can take more cameras and connect to my 4 older cameras and to the network reliably.

Comment: build them yourself from capture cards, camera's and OBS (don't see them in chrome though, but in OBS)

Answer (score 0):

[Security Camera Warehouse](https://www.getscw.com/) sells 16 camera systems that are stand-alone network configured cameras. The NVR (network video recorder) also has a local network port to enable connection for the Chrome feed you request. You may also find there are other systems of similar configuration.

Vandal-proof is a completely different consideration. SCW (and others) sell various types of cameras, some pretty vulnerable, others, not so much. Dome cameras are going to be more resistant, but a well placed rock or round will certainly disable such a camera.

It would be necessary to create a transparent enclosure for the camera of your choice to provide a second layer of protection.

Comment: Is there a way to buy such system on amazon? I already have 4 dvr cameras but the dvr is from annke and is causing a lot of issues. I want to replace it with another system that can take more cameras and connect to my 4 older cameras and to the network reliably.

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit your original post to reflect these conditions you've added in this comment. I would not have made this suggestion given those conditions.